# Closed topic, leads to non-existant topic

Tags: support

This question: [unloading data from oracle dbf files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/unloading-data-from-oracle-dbf-files)

Was closed as a duplicate. I went to find out the original question (and answer): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43637/restore-oracle-database-from-dbf-files

And received a "Page not found"?

Answer (score 8):

After being closed as a duplicate, the duplicate was *also* closed, and subsequently deleted. I thought that there were checks in place that didn't allow that sequence of events to happen, as leaving orphaned duplicates isn't very useful, but I'll have to check up on that. It obviously *can* happen, and that's the explanation why you're seeing a page not found error - you don't have enough rep to see deleted questions.

I've [re-opened the closed question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/unloading-data-from-oracle-dbf-files).